# How to save/store random number temporarily?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am creating a Yahzee game, and I want it to save a 'dice' roll, temporarily.

```py
import random

roll = random.randint(0, 6)
print("Dice 1: " + roll)
print("Dice 2: " + roll)
input = "Save die?"
if input == "Dice 2":
    print("Dice 1: " + roll)
    # Print Dice 2's number above, below
```

It should output:

```
Dice 1: 3
Dice 2: 6
Save Die? Die 2
Dice 1: 2
Dice 2: 6
```

How do I make it save the number, so I can use it, but then after 6 moves, 5 Rolls and choosing the play, it will erase.

Comment: you are only rolling one time and it is saved in the roll variable if you need to store every roll, use a list to store it all roll values.

Comment: @AlbinPaul, but I want to call that number again up to the next 5 times, w/o it changing

Comment: @SpartanGolf, try to run your code and fix the bugs by yourself. It  is better to learn programming…

Comment: Use 2 different variable, one for each dice: `roll1` and `roll2`. Convert `int` to `str` for printing. Use `input()` function and don’t name your variable `input`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is a Yahzee game, but I think you need a simple data structure like `list` to save your results and empty the list when it is necessary.

```py
import random

results = []
move_num = 6
while True:
    for i in range(move_num):
        dices = [random.randint(0, 6), random.randint(0, 6)]
        print('Dice 1: {}'.format(dices[0]))
        print('Dice 2: {}'.format(dices[1]))
        decision = int(input('Save die?'))
        if decision in [1, 2]:
            results.append(dices[decision-1])
        else:
            print('wrong dice number')
    print('results are {}'.format(results))
    results.clear()
```

I do not understand the game rules, hope this could help you.

Comment: You ought to let the OP find its answer by him/her self. He/she didn’t even tried its own code.